# Type declaration/inference in Eclipse/JSDT

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdoc, jsdt

I would like to specify in Eclipse/JSDT the type of an instance variable as in the following example:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function A() {
    /** @type Node */
    this.x = document.createElement("p");
}
```

The IDE, however, does not recognise the type of `x`. On the other hand, a declaration like

```
/** @type Node */
var x;
```

does work, i.e. in this case, `x` is known to have the type of a `Node`.

If I add

```
A.prototype.x = new Node();
```

to the first example, `x` will be known as a variable of type `Node`. However, this code does not run.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** @type Node*/
A.prototype.x = undefined;
```